# Multi-threaded issue with Task in C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

I've got a case that might be useful to analyze and extract some conclusions.

I've got a class that implements ITaskWorker, and each Task can run simultaneously with other Task connected with a scheduling engine.
Suppose Task A runs a job for object A_1 with B1...BN attributes, while for each attribute a command line runs and gives results (which is blocked until an answer is recieved from the command line process).

This means that for Task B we can schedule the same A_1 with B1...BN attributes.

- For the following piece of code and explanation, could you find something that might resolve in threads interrupting each other (deadlocks, race conditions, starvation)?
- How can I ensure that there isn't a multi threaded issue here?
- I think starvation cannot be an issue here, unless there are a lot of tasks of the same type that other types cannot get to be done (see below explanation about the code). I don't see a case for deadlock, but there might be a race condition on mainLocaker or connectionLockers data members (because of the same variable and collection that's are used across multiple methods).
- There cannot be the same key in the dictionary (I've verified that: [b_i.A_Name + "_" + b_i.B_Name] creates a unique key)

I've got this code in C#. Please notice that mainLocker and connectorsLockers is being used in several methods like doTaskOfTypeX, so several 'types' of workers might lock it in different parts of code:

```
private static object mainLocker = new Object();
private static Dictionary<string, object> connectionLockers = new Dictionary<string,object>();

private doTaskOfTypeA()
{
     // ... initialize A from task parameters
     var attibutes = getListOfAttribuesByObject(A);
     bool localLocalTaken = false;
     foreach (B b_i in attibutes)
     {
        try{
        lock (mainLocker)
        {
              if (!typeLockers.ContainsKey(b_i.A_Name + "_" + b_i.B_Name))
              {
                   typeLockers.Add(b_i.A_Name + "_" + b_i.B_Name, new       object()); 
              }                 
        }

        localLocalTaken = false;
        Monitor.Enter(connectionLockers[b_i.A_Name + "_" + b_i.B_Name, ref localLocalTaken);
        if (localLocalTaken)
        {
            var calcObj = callCLIProcess();    // a CMD call is in here
            if (calcObj != null)
            {
                 // do things with calcObj
            }
            else
            {
                 jobResult = new ScheduleTaskResult(ResultTypes.Failed);
            }
        }
        }
        catch 
        {
            jobResult = new ScheduleTaskResult(ResultTypes.Failed);
            throw; 
        }
        finally
        {
             if (localLocalTaken)
             {                    
                  Monitor.Exit(connectionLockers[b_i.A_Name + "_" + b_i.B_Name]);
             }
         }            
     }
}
```

Comment: You have typo in variable names: `localLocalTaken` and `lockTaken`

Comment: edited fix... The typo wasn't in the original code, only in the cleaned one here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no issue here.

The [// do things with calcObj] notation had a code from an external library that didn't work too well :-)